# multiple buttons to generate one thing

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am new around I am trying to create an app to do several things

> 1

when I choose the first button it will randomly choose a letter, eg. **a** the second button will do the same from an another text eg. **b** and a third button call generate will shuffle the letters and we can have either **ab** or **ba** word, that words will generate in a text label.

> 2

same things but several choose buttons (letters a,b,,d,e,f etc.), maybe 5! generation button again and  shuflle letters and generate 5 differents words(abcdef-fbdacf etc.) in differents text labels
I am stuck please help me.

this is a part of my project

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. Edit your question and put the text there.

Comment: @0X0nosugar It's [MIT App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/about-us.html). I think that's about as textual as it gets.

Comment: Thanks @Mike M. , I didn't know that. Looks interesting. I added the tag to the post, maybe OP is lucky and someone can help

Comment: Did you get 1) running? Where exactly did you get stuck? You don't want us to write your homework, do you?